# Command 'uwsgi' not found

Tags: flask, uwsgi

I have installed "uwsgi" using pip method. But when I run uwsgi, I'm getting "Command 'uwsgi' not found, but can be installed with" error.
If I again try to install using pip, I'm getting

```
Collecting uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
Successfully installed uwsgi-2.0.18
```

which means it's already been installed.

What else am I missing out here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to do this

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y uwsgi
```

Comment: Maybe the asker is misunderstanding how `pip` works, but I don't think this is what they want to do, and if it is, it would be helpful to explain the difference between installing via `pip` and via APT (we should definitely not need to do both as you imply here)

Comment: @Zanna you are right here. This was just to get going here. For the detailed answer the asker can have a look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073829/uwsgi-wont-reload-restart-or-let-me-run-service

Comment: @Zanna, If I'm not wrong, pip will install the given software as a python module. Since pip way was not successful, I also gave a try to apt method, which will install the library to the OS. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly which method worked out for me because I tried installing and uninstalling in both methods and finally it's working now. I need to test the behavior again by uninstalling both in my system or I have to test in Virtualbox, to get to know exactly which method got succeeded.